# Integrating Apache Shiro with Play 1.2

Tags: java, security, shiro, playframework-1.x

I've developed an application using Play Framework 1.2. I've read on several sites that it is possible to integrate Apache Shiro with Play 2.x.

However, is there any example available to integrate Apache Shiro with the version 1.x of the Play Framework?

Answer (score 0):

See this https://github.com/wsargent/play-shiro

In particular, Shiro assumes a stateful session strategy, which goes against Play's stateless application. Internally, Shiro uses a ThreadLocal to reference the session; shiro-web has a way of disabling session creation, but since Play isn't built on the Servlet model, I've created analogues for Play that will never create a session.

Comment: There is a version of this plugin for Play 1.x ?